# Grouping with Knedo datasource / grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I accomplish this in Kendo Grid/Datasource?

I have data that looks something like this:

```
Month | Value
--------------
1     |  10
1     |  15
1     |  30
2     |  5
2     |  7
3     |  4
```

I would like to group that data by month and output it to a grid in this form:

```
Month | Sum(Value)
------------------
1     |  55
2     |  12
3     |  4
```

I don't want any group headers and collapsable groups with items on it, I just want that simple output.

How can I do that in Kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think out of the box kendo could get you what you are wanting.  You could manually massage the data into the structure you want, and then bind that to a kendo grid.

Take your array of data, group by month, then sum up the value(s);

```
    var g = {};
    var data = myData; // Or however you get your data
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var obj = data[i];
      if(g[obj.month] === undefined) {
        g[obj.month] = obj.value;
      }
      else {
        g[obj.month] += obj.value;
      }
    }

    var results = [];
    for(var j in g) {
      if(g.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        results.push({ month: j, value: g[j]});
      }
    }
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/pipinodoca/1/edit?js,output